# ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```

When ı run this code;

```
ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ı get thiserror everytime.
How can ı solve this problem?

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5 and PyQtWebEngine?

Comment: I installed it via apt. My Os is Lubuntu

Comment: you could indicate the exact commands you used